# Retrieve UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as a lowercase string

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm using a JDBC `PreparedStatement` directly from a Java application, something like:

```
stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE ...");
...
String mycolumn = stmt.getString("mycolumn");
```

The type of `mycolumn` is `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`. This is a Microsoft SQL Server-supported binary data type of 128 bits, representing a UUID, which gets automatically converted to string.

The problem is, I would like to retrieve this string in lowercase. When using C# with Entity Framework, the string is always lowercase (as shown in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-6.0)). However, in JDBC (using the latest JDBC driver from Microsoft) it always comes out in uppercase.

I can work around this, e.g.

```
connection.prepareStatement("SELECT lower(mycolumn) FROM mytable WHERE ...")
```

but that makes it less efficient (it's a performance-critical application) because the data comes in as a string (36 bytes + overhead) instead of a 16-byte binary number.

Another workaround:

```
 stmt.getString("mycolumn").toLowercase()
```

but that is more processing than necessary, as the binary number first gets converted to uppercase, and then gets converted to lowercase.

Is there an option that makes the `getString` method directly return a lowercase string?

Comment: Ave you considered`getBytes` instead of `getString`?

Comment: How a GUID is displayed is determined by the presentation layer, not the SQL layer; it's not returned in lowercase or uppercase. SSMS, for example, displays `uniqueidentifier` values as uppercase, but ADS in lowercase. *If*, however, you `CONVERT` the value within T-SQL to a `varchar` first, both display an **uppercase** value; demonstrating that it was the presentation layer that chose what case the `uniqueidentifier` was provided in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered `getBytes` instead of `getString`?  If you're not happy with how Java converts a UNIQUEIDENTIFER to a string, provide your own implementation.